# Why is the generation 0 and 1 heap size is climbing with stairway pattern, and collections still growing?

Tags: .net, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have an asp.net 4.7.2 webservice under IIS 10, that is a 32 bit process.
I could not switch to 64 bitness (a legacy native dll is used).
My application even when under stress test have a odd behaviour :

1. The Gen 0 and 1 heap size is climbing with a "stairway pattern" and is still ever growing.
2. The Gen 0,1,2 collection are still ever growing also : and I can observer that more or less : Gen 0 collection = 2* Gen 1 collection = 2* Gen 2 collection

[image]

I suspect a memoryleak and I am tracking for it. But have you got any explanation about the behaviour observed for the point 1 and 2 ? Could you hel me understand what's could going on ?
For your information even after 3h/4h hours my application does not crash : after 1h30 the Gen 0 heap size is still growing bit by bit, the gen 1 heap size is divided by half after a garbage collection and the gen 2 heap size is still climbing.

Comment: Looks like there could be a leak, yes. Have you considered running a monitoring program that would help you understand what is actually being held in memory at that point?

Comment: agree with @LasseV.Karlsen on both points; a: yes, these charts *may* suggest a leak, and b: the easiest way to find out both "if" and "what" would be a memory profiler; random guesses: "static event handlers", "infinite in-memory logs", "shared and retained DB-context" - but the reality is: guessing isn't usually a good way of investigating this kind of issue

Comment: I could only use debugdiag and still searching how to use perfview.  But yes I  am working on the hunt of  the leak. @MarcGravell : Thanks for the ususals suspects list. In a normal situation the Gen x collection should not be cumulative and linear as in my snapshot?

Comment: With DebugDiag you can take hang dumps and that's usually enough for memory analysis if you know how to use tools like WinDbg. Tess has tons of classic cases recorded with hints on how to move on, https://www.tessferrandez.com/postindex/ If you find it hard to follow, you'd better hire an experienced professional to help (one way is to open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com) instead of pushing yourself too hard.